# Using Zend Lucene to search Office 2003 or older files

Tags: php, zend-framework, solr, lucene, solr-cell

I know there are already objects supporting Office 2007 files, but is there any native Office 2003 or earlier support ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be anything bundled with [`Zend_Search_Lucene`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html#zend.search.lucene.overview), for those.

Still, considering it can index [HTML documents](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html#zend.search.lucene.index-creation.html-documents), if you can find a way to convert your Office 2003 documents to HTML *(at least, for indexing -- keeping to original version alonside the HTML one, for consultation)*, you might be able to index those...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend indexing the documents with [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) and [Tika](http://lucene.apache.org/tika/) together and using [JSON](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolJSON) to search your Solr/Lucene index from PHP. See the [ExtractingRequestHandler (Solr wiki page) article](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler) for more information.